# Genesis block - why does the address linked to it contain all zeros?

Tags: ethereum

Who/what is the address with all zeros, and how come I see (on various blockchain explorers) that ETH is being sent to and from this address? Who has access to these funds?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like it belongs on http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Where did I post it?

Comment: You posted on StackOverflow, which is for questions about programming, algorithms, and software development.

Answer (score 3):

The genesis block is a special block which was mined by nobody and therefore is associated with the account [0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000](https://live.ether.camp/account/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000).

The reason why you see people sending Ether to or mining Ether at this account is that people misconfigured their miners and [set their coinbase to a wrong value or to 0](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/35xvd7/miner_as/) which is mapped to the account 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

In addition, it's nearly impossible to generate the private key for this address and people can use it as [proof-of-burn account on the Ethereum blockchain](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3il93h/a_proposal_on_the_effective_use_of_address/).